# How to write a numeric field in a VBA expression using MS Access 2016?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, textbox, formatting

I have a code line referencing a field as a Date format. I need to reference another field as numeric format.

This is my code for a date format field:

```
Private Sub cmbsearch_Click()
Dim varFilter As Variant, stdcard_id As String, txtname As String, txtrecord 
As String, strTableName As String
strTableName = "tbl01"
    If IsNull(Me.stdcard_id) Then
        Me.stdcard_id.SetFocus: Exit Sub
    End If

varFilter = "[dateofbirth]= # "& Forms!frm_stid_name_record & "#"
....
End Sub
```

This is my code line for a numeric format field, but I don't know to write the code after the "=" symbol

```
varFilter = "[std_id]="
```

Comment: Your headline says MS Access but your tags say Excel-VBA. Please [edit] and clarify! If you use the wrong tags, it shows up in the wrong categories and you might not get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Dim stdid As Long

stdid = Val(Forms!frm_stid_name_record)

varFilter = "[std_id]=" & stdid & " "
```

Comment: I apologize for my mistake.
My code lines are from VBA Access 2016 cmd button. 
I have a Form with three TextBoxes already declared in the previous post.
@Dy.Lee. In my code, I need to include 'Forms!frm_stid_name_record...'


'varFilter = "[std_id]=" & Forms!frm_stid_name_record & " "  '

A Compilation Error Type mistmatch occurs in: 'Forms!frm_stid_name_record'

I have been googling but not found any help to fix the Error.

Comment: @SebastianSalazar, If Forms!frm_stid_name_record is a character, you can convert it to a number and then complete the sql statement.

Comment: In my Db Forms!frm_stid_name_record is the Form name.  
My tbl01 has three fields: 'std_id (Double)', 'stdname (string)', 'stdrecord (Double)'
For my cmd button in my Form I am trying to use two Functions:
'txtname = Nz(DLookup("[stdname]", strTableName, varFilter), "N/A")'
'txtrecord = Nz(DLookup("[txtrecord]", strTableName, varFilter), "N/A")'
Thererefore, I need to fix the Error to test above code lines.
I'm confused, since, I thought I was working with VBA code.